# Jquery - Setting form select-field "selected" value only works after refresh

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I want to use a form select-field for users to select their country of residence, which shows the IP based country as default value (plus the IP address next to it);

Location info (ipinfodb.com) is working. I'm passing "country" and "ip" to the function, which should modify select-field and ip adress

Problem: 
IP adress works, but the select-field only updates after I hit refresh.

Can someone tell me why?

Here is the code:
HTML

```
<select name="setup_changeCountry" id="setup_changeCountry">
     <option value="AL-Albania">Albanien</option>
     <option value="AD-Andorra">Andorra</option>
     <option value="AM-Armenia">Armenien</option>
     <option value="AU-Australia">Australien</option>
     ...
</select>
<div class="setup_IPInfo">
    <span>Your IP</span>
    <span class="ipAdress"> -- ip --</span>
</div>
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
function morph(country,ip) >> passed from function, called on DOMContentLoaded
{
var ipAdress = ip;
$('.ipAdress').text(ipAdress);

var countryForm = country; 
$('#setup_changeCountry  option').each(function()
    {
    if ($(this).val().substr(0,2) == countryForm)
        {
        $(this).attr('selected', "true");
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for any clues on how to fix this.

Frequent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simplify your loop immensely and let jQuery do the work:

```
$("#setup_changeCountry option[value$='" + country + "']").attr('selected', true);
```

make sure:

- the case matches (your country must then also begin with a capital letter)
- you execute this code after the DOM's loaded, otherwise you might be trying to select an option that doesnt exist yet

Comment: I used each(), because I first needed to "substr" the option value (AL-Albania > AL). Your code would be much simpler, but then I would have to edit all options to only show the two letters (AL). Thanks for the info anyways.

Comment: @frequent, either i didnt understand you, or you're wrong. [value^=''] looks at the first part of the string, [value$=''] looks at the last part of the string. it performs substr itself!

Comment: Great help. Thanks! I need to check for the first 2 letters, so it would be [value^="]. Still it doesn't help with the field only being updated after reloading the page.

Comment: make sure you're calling the function on $(document).ready(), and if that doesnt work, then make sure your javascript variables are where they are at the expected time. try and log them to the console for example

Comment: Got it... the function was called before all of the info (IP, country) was available and stored. AND I did the whole thing in Jquery-Mobile, that means the (now) correctly set select field was hidden and a replacement button was displayed still showing the first option. Also managed to correct this, so I'm a happy camper. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

It's selected="selected" not selected="true", therefore:

`$(this).attr('selected', 'selected');`

(Also you could skip the `var ipAdress` and just pass `ip` in the next line)

Comment: `selected` is a Boolean value, rather than an attribute=value pair, so it's properly `$(this).attr('selected',true);` / `$(this).removeAttr('selected');`.

Comment: Yes, that's true (and it's more correct than my version). I was only making that remark about the (string, string) type. Thanks for pointing that out. Having that `selected="selected"` syntax is a result of XML document-derived (limited) syntax in XHTML.

Comment: it took me a while to figure out it is in fact "true", too :-)

Answer (score 0):

you should use:

```
 $(document).ready(name_of_function);
```

this way you can run the function to select the country. You can use this function for that:

```
function morph(country,ip){
    var ipAdress = ip;
    $('.ipAdress').text(ipAdress);
    var countryForm = country; 
    $("#setup_changeCountry option[value$='" + country + "']").attr('selected', true);
}
```